# Servlet WebServlet multiple urlPattern

Tags: servlets

I must write a servlet that should do multiple operations according to the button I press on the html page.

I have one button that is a Insert into the Db, another is a Delete, another is a Select.

So I would like my servlet will do all those three operations in the doGet method.

My clue was to put

```
@WebServlet("select", "insert", "delete")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    ...

        @Override
            protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                String path = request.getServletPath()!=null?request.getServletPath():"";
                switch(path){
                case "/select":
                    ...
                break;
                switch(path){
                case "/insert":
                    ...
                break;
                switch(path){
                case "/delete":
                    ...
                break;
```

then, into the javascript file it would have been (for select)

```
var req={
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/AngularDb/select',
    }
$http(req);
```

and into the web.xml

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

But all this doesn't work.

May you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: 1. This is not a design-patterns question 2. Please add the error you are getting or the stack trace to the question

Comment: 1) Sorry, I wrote "url-pattern", I don't know why it selected design pattern.
2) I don't get any error. It just doesn't go into the servlet

Comment: You got the paths right but not url patterns. They have to be the same. And get rid of that web.xml entry.

Comment: Sorry, I just not sure I got your answer:
So you say that my problem is into the web.xml, don't you?

Should it be:  
<url-pattern>/select</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/insert</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/delete</url-pattern>
?